# assign obtained value to a variable and reuse it in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Here is the spider code am using.
The problem i am having is that i want to extract the data as by the xpath in 'Building' and reuse it for all the data that will be pulled using the second for loop. I am very new to scrapy, so please help. I know it may be an idiotic question for many of you, but it's trivial to me.

```
import scrapy
import re


class ShinjukDataByBuilding(scrapy.Spider):
name = "displaybybuilding2"
start_urls = ['http://suumo.jp/jj/chintai/ichiran/FR301FC001/?ar=030&bs=040&ta=13&sc=13104&sngz=&po1=12&pc=50']

def parse(self, response):
    for div in response.xpath('div[@class="cassetteitem"]'):
        yield{
            'Building' = div.xpath('//div[@class="cassetteitem_content-title"]/text()').extract()
            for tbody in response.xpath('//table[@class="cassetteitem_other"]//tbody'):
                'BuildingName' = Building,
                'Property Link':response.xpath('//tr//td[@class="ui-text--midium ui-text--bold"]/a/@href').extract_first(' ').strip(),
                'Property Code':response.xpath('//tr//td[@class="ui-text--midium ui-text--bold"]/a/@href').re('[a-z]+\=[0-9]+')





        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one element to yield is one iteration of your inner loop. So you would call yield for every iteration of your inner loop.

```
import scrapy
import re

class ShinjukDataByBuilding(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "displaybybuilding2"
    start_urls = ['http://suumo.jp/jj/chintai/ichiran/FR301FC001/?ar=030&bs=040&ta=13&sc=13104&sngz=&po1=12&pc=50']

    def parse(self, response):
        for div in response.xpath('div[@class="cassetteitem"]'):
            building = div.xpath('//div[@class="cassetteitem_content-title"]/text()').extract()
            for tbody in response.xpath('//table[@class="cassetteitem_other"]//tbody'):
                yield {
                    'BuildingName': building,
                    'Property Link':response.xpath('//tr//td[@class="ui-text--midium ui-text--bold"]/a/@href').extract_first(' ').strip(),
                    'Property Code':response.xpath('//tr//td[@class="ui-text--midium ui-text--bold"]/a/@href').re('[a-z]+\=[0-9]+')
                }
```

Also note that `'Building' = div.xpath('//div[@class="cassetteitem_content-title"]/text()').extract()` is wrong syntax, you would need a `:` instead of `=`

Your code seems to have a few more problems. When you call `div.xpath('//div[@class="cassetteitem_content-title"]/text()').extract()` you go through *all* `div`s that have that class. To only get those that are relative children to the outer `div` you should use `.//div` instead. See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-relative-xpaths